# Show that $\operatorname{Tor}(A, B)$ is always a torsion group

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have found proof of this here https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/alg_topo/sol2.pdf but I find it very difficult to follow

I am trying to prove this for myself but I have many doubts, this is my attempt:

We know that $\operatorname{Tor}(A,B)=\operatorname{Tor}(T(A),T(B))$ where $T(A)$ and $T(B)$ are the subgroup of $A$ and $B$ respectively consisting of the torsion elements of $A$ and $B$. I could assume that there are $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $T(A)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $T(B)\cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$? In this case, conclude that $\operatorname{Tor}(A,B)\cong\mathbb{Z}/(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$ where $(m,n)=\gcd(m,n)$? Thank you.

***Edit:*** this is a part of Exercise 6 of Hatcher's topology book page $267$

Comment: First $Tor$ or $Tor^1$ only recognize torsion part and vanishes on free part. Second you have to check $Tor^1$ is additive functor in the sense $Tor^1(A\oplus B,-)=Tor^1(A,-)\oplus Tor^1(B,-)$. Symmetrically, the argument applies to $Tor^1(-,A\oplus B)$ as well. Then it reduces to compute $Tor^1(T(A),T(B))$ only. By definition of $Tor^1(T(A),T(B))$, you just pick a resolution of $T(B)$ say $0\to F_1\to F_0\to B\to 0$ and tensor this complex by $T(A)$. Then $Ker(T(A)\otimes F_1\to T(A)\otimes F_0)$ is $Tor^1(T(A),T(B))$. The computation can be done similarly against $T(A)$. They are the same.

Comment: You can't assume there are $n$ and $m$ like you describe. What you can do (and what's happening in the notes you posted) is construct a map of direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}/(b)$s to B and play some games with the s.e.s. coming from this surjective map.

Comment: I wonder if their is a topological proof of this fact. Surely there must be when all involved is finitely generated...

Comment: @user45765 
How can I prove then that $ker(T(A)\otimes F_1\to T(A)\otimes F_0)$ is a torsion group?

Comment: @user402543 First $ker(T(A)\otimes_Z F_1\to T(A)\otimes F_0)\subset T(A)\otimes_Z F_1$. All subgroup of torsion subgroup is torsion. In particular, you show $T(A)\otimes_Z F_1$ is torsion. This is normally done by choosing a representative and multiply by a large enough factor to turn off individual factors.

Comment: @user45765 So I should multiply it by the product of all possible orders of elements of $T(A)$? Could this multiplication be infinite? With this I would show that $T(A)\otimes F_1$ is a torsion group where the order of $T(A)\otimes F_1$ would be the multiplication of all possible orders of elements of $T(A)$?

Comment: @user402543 Consider $\oplus_p Z_p$ where $p$ runs through primes. You can't find such $n$ universally for all elements. To show $T(A)\otimes F_1$ is torsion, note that $F_1=\oplus_i Z$ and tensor commutes with direct sum. So $T(A)\otimes F_1=\oplus_i T(A)$. (i.e. You have identical copies of $T(A)$ direct sum. Say $x\in T(A)\otimes F_1$. We have $a=\sum_i a_i$ with $a_i$ in individual components of $T(A)$. Note that sum is finite sum and there is $n_i\in N, n_i a_i=0$. So we have $n=\prod_i n_i$ which is a finite product. This gives $a$ torsion.

Comment: @user45765 
Thank you very much, I have it, it seems perfect as you do.